# Why am I getting "Project facet Cloud Foundry Standalone Application version 1.0 is not supported"?

Tags: java, eclipse, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-tools

I'm trying to deploy the following project from [IBM developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/) to [Bluemix](https://www.bluemix.net/):

[Building a Java EE app on IBM Bluemix Using Watson and Cloudant](https://developer.ibm.com/bluemix/2014/10/17/building-java-ee-app-ibm-bluemix-using-watson-cloudant/)

through the Bluemix plugin in [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/) (Called: [IBM Eclipse Tools for Bluemix](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/ibm-eclipse-tools-bluemix)). However I keep getting the following error

> Project facet Cloud Foundry Standalone Application version 1.0 is not
>   supported

[image]

Used Versions:

- Eclipse Version: Mars Release (4.5.0) Build id: 20150621-1200
- IBM® Eclipse Tools for Bluemix Version: 1.0.4 Build id: 20150801_1001

There is no issue when I do this through [Cloud Foundry CLI](https://www.ng.bluemix.net/docs/starters/install_cli.html) `cf push`

Comment: What this tells is that the project you are trying to deploy is a stand alone java web application and not a liberty profile application that can be deployed on to bluemix. Were you able to run this app locally on a liberty profile server? Try that first before deploying it to bluemix. This can be done by choosing the liberty profile server in the wizard instead of bluemix. If that is not possible, you may have to convert your application into a liberty profile application. I do not know how easy or difficult that could be. You can download liberty profile tools from with your eclipse JEE

Comment: @SasikanthBharadwaj It got deployed fine using the Cloud Foundry CLI (cf push). The app is working fine. This issue happens only when I use the bluemix plugin.

Comment: Then it could just be an issue with the project facets - try removing the Standalone Application version 1.0 facet from the project via project -> properties -> project facets

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Remove the `Cloud Foundry Standalone Application` version 1.0 facet from the project via `project -> properties -> project facets`.

[image]

Bluemix tools maps projects to bluemix runtimes via `project facets` so that different runtimes would be associated with different projects.

It's probably just that the stand alone facet which is probably associated with cloudfoundry tools isn't supported by bluemix tools plugin

Comment: For those who could not uncheck the *Cloud Foundry Standalone Application* from the project facets because of an error message '*cloudfoundry.standalone.app 1.0 cannot be uninstalled*', here's a trick:

Open the project's file *.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml* and remove the `<installed facet="cloudfoundry.standalone.app" version="1.0"/>` tag

Answer (score 6):

As @Ghurdyl mentions in the comments, If you cannot deselect the CloudFoundry Standalone Applicaiton, then remove the facet from the project's settings file (`.settings/org.eclipse.wst.common.project.facet.core.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <installed facet="cloudfoundry.standalone.app" version="1.0"/>
  <installed facet="java" version="10"/>
</faceted-project>
```

to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faceted-project>
  <installed facet="java" version="10"/>
</faceted-project>
```